# insert Data Into MySQL Database Using Php PDO Probloem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am trying to insert to my database using PDO but I have a problem with my code:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`` 'user`, `pass`) VALUES (?,?) ``' at line 1' in C:\wamp64\www\Pd\sql.php on line 16
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`` 'user`, `pass`) VALUES (?,?) ``' at line 1 in C:\wamp64\00\00\sql.php on line 16

My code:

```
<?php
$dbname ="snabel_db"; 
$dbhost ="localhost"; 
$dbuser ="root"; 
$dbpass =""; 
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$dbhost.';charset=utf8', ''.$dbuser.'', ''.$dbpass.'') or die();

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

if(isset($_POST['add'])){


    $user2 = $_POST['user'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql ="INSERT INTO `user`('user`, `pass`) VALUES (:user1,:pass1)";
    $sqlreuslt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $pdoexec = $sqlreuslt->execute(array(":user1"=>$user2,":pass1"=>$pass2));
    if($pdoexec){
        echo 'DOne';
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sql Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sql.php">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="user"><br>
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: firstly I'd suggest changing your connection to `$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$dbhost.';charset=utf8', $dbuser, $dbpass ) or die();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDO constructor looked to be incorrect - a strange use of single quotes when, for the user and password, they were not needed as they were assigned as variables.

You might also like to broaden the `isset` condition to include the other POST variables that you expect to be present and also test for a successfully prepared statement too?

Common thought these days is that passwords should be stored as a hash rather than as plain text - to that end [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) should be on interest.

```
<?php
    /* sql.php */

    $dbname ="snabel_db"; 
    $dbhost ="localhost"; 
    $dbuser ="root"; 
    $dbpass =""; 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$dbhost.';charset=utf8', $dbuser, $dbpass ) or die();

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    if( isset( $_POST['add'],$_POST['user'],$_POST['pass'] ) ){
        $user2 = $_POST['user'];
        $pass2 = $_POST['pass'];

        $sql ="insert into `user` ( `user`, `pass` ) values ( :user1, :pass1 )";
        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $pdoexec = $stmt->execute( array( ":user1" => $user2, ":pass1" =>$pass2 ) );

            if( $pdoexec ){
                echo 'Done';
            }else{
                echo 'error';
            }
        } else {
            echo "statement error";
        }
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sql Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sql.php">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="user"><br>
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" name="add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 't7-' for column 'user' at row 1' in C:\wamp64\www\Pd\sql.php on line 22
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 't7-' for column 'user' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\Pd\sql.php on line 22

Answer (score 1):

Wrong quote here

```
"INSERT INTO `user`('user`, `pass`)
```

You need

```
"INSERT INTO `user`(`user`, `pass`)
```